# Retrying GET request until a certain value from http response in JMeter is present

Tags: loops, csv, jmeter

I have a following situation. I need to wait for a certain value from get request from response body. I need to loop this quest and when the desired value is present in response, exit the loop, and call new request that needs to execute as well in loop until another value is shown in response.

Thing is I have **Thread Group** ( In thread group I've set 'Loop Count' to 3, but it will be dynamically set based on previous tests, but for the sake of explaining my situation let's say its 3 loops. ) and in that Thread Group i have a **CSV Data Set Config** from which I use IDs that I pass into the GET request (also for the sake of example have 3 rows and in each row unique ID).

So basically I would like to iterate through my Thread Group 3 times, using different IDs on each iteration for GET requests (one of IDs from CSV rows ), but to retry a GET request a number of times ( infinite isn't an option, so lets say 200 times ) until it's response contain certain value or cancel the test.

**Ideal scenario would be like this:**

**GET request** with id='123' => check in response if the value that I need is there, if not

RETRY **GET request** with id='123' = > check in response if the value that I need is there, if not

RETRY **GET request** with id='123' = > check in response if the value that I need is there, if there:

start new **GET request** with id='456' => check in response if the value that I need is there, if not

RETRY **GET request** with id='456' = > check in response if the value that I need is there, if not

RETRY **GET request** with id='456' = > check in response if the value that I need is there, if not

200th RETRY with no value that i need - exit the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put your HTTP Request sampler under the Loop Controller
2. Add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) after the HTTP Request and use the following __groovy() function as the condition:

   ```
   ${__groovy(prev.getResponseDataAsString().contains('value-you-are-looking-for'),)}
   ```

   replace `value-you-are-looking-for` with the actual anticipated value

   [image]
3. Add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler as a child of the If Controller and set it to `Break Current Loop`

   [image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in my case. If I understood correctly, when condition in IF controller is fulfilled, the Flow Control Action will break the current loop, and it will start another with another id? 

The thing is I am waiting for 'UPDATE' in response, and I've put this 'UPDATE' in IF Controller condition as per your suggestion, but the response I am getting when request is executed first time is not containing that 'UPDATE' yet, but nevertheless with this code from you, test jumps straight to next ID ( new call ) without trying to recall request previous request.

Comment: You told `" and in that Thread Group i have a CSV Data Set Config"` and if `" this doesn't work in my case"` it means that you're lying. Move CSV Data Set Config out of the Loop Controller and "this" should start "working in your case". More information: [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) and [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

Comment: Please take a look at these pictures -> https://imgur.com/a/D8IBYGs ( its imgur link ). Maybe you can see what if I've done something wrong here, because it does not loop one request until if condition is met.  I really appreciate your insight on this matter. All best, D.

Comment: Set number of loops in the Loop Controller to `3` and the number of loops in the Thread Group to be equal  to number of lines in CSV

Comment: Thank you Dimiti T. I've now got the desired flow. Thank you so much.